# Calculate the inverse of $h(x)=f(2x)$

Tags: calculus, inverse

I have to calculate the inverse $f^{-1}(x)$ of $y=f(x)=2x-1$ and it is simple for this kinds of functions

Let $x=f(y)=2y-1$

$x+1=2y$

$\displaystyle\frac{x+1}{2}=y$

We now have the inverse $f^{-1}(x)=\displaystyle\frac{x+1}{2}$

But how am I goin to find the inverse of functions like  $h(x)=f(2x)$?

Note that they are completely two different assignments

Comment: Hint: What is $f(2x)$?

Comment: Note that it is two separate assignments.

Answer (score 2):

If what you need to invert is not  given explicitly but contains  some generic invertible function, you need to express the inverse using the inverse of that function.

You can think of $f(2x)$ as the *composition* of two functions. The function "multiplication by two", so $x \mapsto 2x$, and $f$. Let us call the multiplication by two function $m$, so $m(x)=2x$. Then $h(x)= (f \circ m)(x)$.

Presumably you heard something like $(f_1\circ f_2)^{-1} = f_2^{-1} \circ f_1^{-1} $.

So $h^{-1}(x) = (m^{-1} \circ f^{-1})(x)$ and you can determine $m^{-1}$ and $f^{-1}$ separately. The first should not be hard for you, and the second depends on $f$, but if $f$ is not given the best you can do is say it is $f^{-1}$, and your answer will involve $f^{-1}$.

More informally, you have $f(2x)$, if you want to undo that you have to first undo $f$, and then divide by two.

Comment: Okay I got $ f_2^{-1} \circ f_1^{-1} = \displaystyle\frac{f^{-1}}{2}$

Comment: But what about $(f_1\circ f_2)^{-1}$ it should be the same

Comment: Yes, it is the same. This is what I said. If you have not seen this, just do not use it in this way. Your result is correct. You can check it by saying $f^{-1}(f(2x))= 2x$. So the inverse of $f(2x)$ is f^{-1}/2.